# Easy and correct way to loop accounts

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a bot for a website where the system logs in with several accounts and does a certain action the problem is when it is time to repeat the process example I have 10 accounts and I would like all accounts to do the same process as the first, the accounts are browned in a txt file. What is the correct way to do this?

Sometimes the function runs ahead of time, I'm new to C # I'm studying

My code looping :/

```
Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t => setMail());
Task.Delay(3500).ContinueWith(t => nextButton());
Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(t => setPass());
Task.Delay(6500).ContinueWith(t => logionButton());
Task.Delay(7500).ContinueWith(t => SucessLogin());
```

Comment: The question is too broad to be a good fit here as there are many different answers. I'd recommend that you investigate using a web driver such as Selenium.

Comment: So make a method that does what you need for one account, and pass in an account to the method.  Now call it 10 times.

Comment: have you tried actually writing a _loop_ yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating 5 independent tasks which will all run together, rather than one after the other. Instead, just collapse them to one `async/await` function:

```
async Task TestStuff(Account account)
{
  await Task.Delay(2000);
  setMail();

  await Task.Delay(3500);
  nextButton();

  await Task.Delay(5000);
  setPass();

  await Task.Delay(6500)
  logionButton();

  await Task.Delay(7500);
  SucessLogin();
}
```

You mentioned that you've got accounts stored in a file. In this example you'll need to create an `Account` class and populate it with the information you get from the file. For example:

```
List<Account> accounts = LoadAccounts("some-file.txt")
foreach(var account in accounts)
{
  await TestStuff(account);
}
```

Comment: Nice!  Thanks you Man!